# SQL in Access and Count Distinct

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need help with Access as it it the first time I use SQL in it and also outside the systems I've used to learn the language (I know, I'm a newbie).

I need to do a Count Distinct for a Query (Query VL) that I've already done on another table (used Query Wizard for it). Need to do it for SOURCE_ACCOUNT_ID column.

Thought I could do it in the 'Criteria' section in Design mode, but it didn't work.

I think this is the best way, but I'm not sure:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS N
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT SOURCE_ACC_ID FROM Query VL) AS T;
```

Now, I don't know where to put it, as in SQL mode this shows up and when I put it in, the values are not shown:

```
SELECT [SQLAExport DEC 2017].SOURCE_ACCOUNT_ID, [SQLAExport DEC 
2017].SAP_ACC, [SQLAExport DEC 2017].SAP_CC, [SQLAExport DEC 
2017].SAP_PRODUCT
FROM [SQLAExport DEC 2017];
```

I know that it might be tremendously easy, but maybe I just can't see it and it's really fustrating :)

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Either you are making things more complicated than they need to be or you are not describing all of the problem.

To start with, why are you using an intermediate query? All it does is get some raw data from the table so just use the table instead.

```
SELECT Count(*) AS N
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT [SOURCE_ACC_ID] FROM [SQLAExport DEC 2017]) AS T
```

Assuming all your table and field names are correct this should work.

If by "where to put it" you mean where to type the code, then leave your existing query alone, start a new blank query and put it in its SQL code.

Comment: I was under stress so maybe I didn't explain myself properly, I apologize. 
That code doesn't seem to work, I saw it in another question and tried it. A window pops up asking about SOURCE_ACC_ID, instead of a table.
Thanks!